# How do I show one column of data a fix value while the other column is shown normally with both columns from the same column data? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am wondering is there a way to forcefully show only one data from a certain column and having another column show the data normally

for example if I have a table like this

```
|User_ID  |  First_name  | Last_Name|
|u1       |  Ben         | Jones    |
|u2       |  Carl        | Smith    |
|u3       |  John        | Jack     |
```

and when I select it I want it to look like this

```
|User_ID  |  First_name  | Last_Name| This is a force space|
|u1       |  Ben         | Jones    | This is Ben          |
|u2       |  Carl        | Smith    | This is Ben          |
|u3       |  John        | Jack     | This is Ben          |
```

I tried using

```
Select User_ID , First_Name , Last_Name , ('this is '+min(First_name)) as'This is a force space' from User
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be what you are looking for

```
Select a.User_ID , a.First_Name , a.Last_Name , 
    ('this is '+min(b.First_name)) as'This is a force space' 
from User as a inner join User as b 
group by  a.User_ID , a.First_Name , a.Last_Name;
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't know you can call the same table twice in the from clause

Comment: Is usual the inner join is often an auto inner join .. eg:for tables that contain hierarchical structures